# Roblox Glitch: Gear is only showing locally and not being shown to other players on the same server

Tags: lua, roblox

I have run into a slight issue with my map. I have given the local player some gear by cloning it out of `ReplicatedStorage` and into their backpack. For some strange reason though, the gear only shows up to the player holding it, and other players on the same server do not see the gear. I have run a test locally and taken a picture to illustrate:
[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akH13.png)

After you click on the link you can see what I mean. There are two players right next to each other and one of them is holding a torch, but you can only see it on his screen. Here is the script I use whenever I am giving a player a torch:

```
    local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
    local torch = ReplicatedStorage.Gear.Torch
    local backpack = player:WaitForChild("Backpack")
    torch:Clone().Parent = backpack
```

As you can see I simply clone the torch out of replicated storage and into the player's backpack. My question is this, do I need to place the torch in some sort of replicated storage for all the other players to be able to see it?

Roblox's documentation on these types of things is quite scarce, so I apologize in advance for not being able to find what is causing this yet. If anyone else has had a similar issue and solved it, some insight would be greatly appreciated. Also, if I need to give more information, please ask and I will provide it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have filteringenabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to networking and preventing players from modifying the server values from local scripts.

Due to this you should focus on having the tool inserted into the backpack from a server script not a local script.

```
game:GetService('Players').PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player) -- Creates an event that triggers on player joins the server
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character) -- Everytime player spawns run code below
    local torch = ReplicatedStorage.Gear.Torch 
    local backpack = player:WaitForChild("Backpack")
    torch:Clone().Parent = backpack
        end)
    end)
end)
```

Have this in a script in ServerScriptService.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick feedback! It makes complete sense why they would have it work this way too.